# Should you unsubscribe from events and dispose of objects in nunit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Is there a guideline as to if we should do reference cleanup in unit tests with NUnit?

```
[Test]
public void Test_AsyncAction_EventRaised()
{
  var someClassToTest = new someClassToTest();
  var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
  someClassToTest.SomeEvent += () => {
    mre.Set();
  }

  someClassToTest.SomeAsyncAction();    
  var eventFired = mre.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

  Assert.IsTrue(eventFired);

  //unsub event?
  //dispose MRE?
}
```

In a normal runtime situation not unsubbing would mean the test fixture would be leaked for as long as the SomeClassToTest was still in mem .. if the SomeClassToTest has a memory leak then that would mean the fixture would leak too.

Classes implementing IDisposable (such as ManualResetEvent) imply that if we don't call Dispose then they'll leak resources.  Is this applicable to unit test scenarios as well?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ that one seems to ask "How do I always clean up?" and this one is more of "Do I always need to clean up?"

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ That question was about how to ensure their database was cleaned up after a test.  In this case, i know how to clean up .. i'm just not sure if it is a best practice for the NUnit framework or not.

Comment: @BillTarbell / @Broots Waymb okay I removed the duplicate flag. Bill, in general and a rule of thumb *anything* that implements `IDisposable` should always dispose to release resources. As far as a guideline I am not sure at this time. Besides what does it hurt to do so, it's better to do something about it then not doing about the references right?

Comment: The `someClassToTest` instance doesn't stay in scope beyond the test itself.  Since the whole object is going out of scope, it will not be holding rooted references to the objects in handlers to its events.

It's rather rare for an object to outlive handlers to its events by a lot, and for those objects in handlers to be expensive to retain.  As such, it should be rather rare to need to unsubscribe from events.  If you're doing it often, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Object will remain in the memory as long as all tests are executed or even less, depends on test executor. So unless instance didn't reference some external resources you will be good to not to clean it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preference is always to have the test code do a proper clean up (unless possibly in the situation that a test fails - in this case I accept resource leaks from that test).  This is due to the following reasons:

- I see test code also as documentation.  Thus I prefer it to show good usage of my SUT (system under test) as well as of other libraries.
- One use case for tests is running them under a memory analyzer to find resource leaks in the SUT.  If, however, the tests themselves introduce resource leaks, it is much harder to get useful results from such analysers - you might not see the wood for the trees.
- If you want to be able to combine tests into larger test suites later, then resource leaks will sum up.  Depending on the type of resource (open files, threads, ...) this can lead to problems.

Comment: A simple way to implement this under NUnit is to make your test class disposable. NUnit will dispose of it when the fixture completes. Of course, this only works for resources held for the life of the TestFixture, not those acquired during individual tests. Those should be disposed in the TearDown.